# Day Count Fraction specified as 1/1 (2006 ISDA section 4.16 a)

Tags: fixed-income

I have a hard time understanding the day count fraction specified as 1/1.

I have never seen an example in which this is used and I have not been able to find any detailed explanation of how it is used.

Can anyone explain when and how it is used? How does it apply to any period? To what type of period does it apply (year, month, week, day)?

I will be most obliged if I could receive an answer on this. 
Kind regards, Mark Lipse

Comment: It means that the year fraction of any non-negative period is 1. See e.g. the QuantLib implementation https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/blob/master/ql/time/daycounters/one.hpp. I can't tell you if this is actually used anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a formulaic way of representing an absolute interest level, to be consistent with other calculation methods and formulae.

A lends \$100 to B at 5% with a 1/1 DCF. Then whatever the time period the interest payment is \$5.

I've worked in linear rates for >10Y and never seen it on any term sheet docs or in standard product pricing.

Comment: Perhaps for inflation swaps ?

Comment: @AntoineConze I genuinely don't know the answer but going on 10y ago I did build a pricer for inflation swaps and I don't recall '1/1/' being involved, im somewhat sure the DCF were still defined by other traditional means.

Comment: just thinking for YY swaps the market always sets year periods to 1 for simplicity so one way to mimic that in a system that requires a DCF as input to building schedules would be to pass such a 1/1 convention.

Comment: yeh I'm sure would work, but the 'act/act icma' convention with yearly frequency would likely be the same, and my guess is since it is more consistent with bonds might be favoured.